# How to update the values when the featured image has changed?

Tags: database, hooks, post-thumbnails

I'm trying to implement this function. It saves in the database the dominant color of the image uploaded as featured image in a post.
It's working perfectly BUT the problem is that it only works when you upload a new image. It doesn't update if you select as featured image an already uploaded image in the library. Is there a way to make it update the colors every time you change the image no matter if it's new or if it was already uploaded?

I'm new to this hooks and filters thing with Wordpress so pardon my ignorance.

Thanks in advance!

```
//Color dominance detection and saving.
add_action('update_post_meta', 'color_dominante', 10, 1);

function color_dominante($attachment_id) {

if (!wp_attachment_is_image($attachment_id)) return;

$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$image = $upload_dir['basedir'].'/'.get_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attached_file', true);

if (!$image) return;
try {
    $dominantColor = ColorThief::getColor($image);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    return;
}
$hex = rgb2hex($dominantColor);

update_post_meta($attachment_id, 'dominant_color_hex', $hex);
update_post_meta($attachment_id, 'dominant_color_rgb', $dominantColor);

$palette = ColorThief::getPalette($image, 8);
update_post_meta($attachment_id, 'color_palette_rgb', $palette);

$hex_palette = array();
foreach($palette as $rgb) {
    $hex_palette[] = rgb2hex($rgb);
}
update_post_meta($attachment_id, 'color_palette_hex', $hex_palette);
}
```